# How to format a side-by-side comparison table?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I was thinking about asking one question, but to do so would require me to show my research so far, and that research would be best presented as a table of features, having similar features in same rows, and compared races / classes etc as columns.

I know this format was used on the main site already, but I can't find Q&A to copy it from. So, how do I do that?

Comment: Relevant MSE post: [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast actually, that's an answer all right, thank you!

Comment: @ThomasMarkov nope, because currently tablets on Stack Exchange have nothing to do with MathJax

Comment: @Mołot Did you read the whole answer, or just the title of the question?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov if the title of linked question is wrong, please correct it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this MSE post for the table formatting/syntax and limitations: [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/335251)

> ### Syntax
>
> Okay, so how do you use tables? We've updated our [formatting
> help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) to give you
> some guidance. But here's an overview for you.
>
> A simple table looks like this:
>
> ```
> | A header | Another header |
> | -------- | -------------- |
> | First    | row            |
> | Second   | row            |
> ```
>
> The result:
>
> | A header | Another header |
> | --- | --- |
> | First | row |
> | Second | row |
>
> #### The rules
>
> - You always need a header row
> - Cells are separated by a *pipe* (`|`) symbol
> - You *can* include leading and trailing pipes but don't have to
> - A header row *has to be* followed by a separator row with the same amount of cells, and you can't have spaces between separators (`-` characters)
>
>   (that's the `|---|---|` line)
> - The amount of space and `-` characters in a cell don't have to line up (but it sure looks nice if it does)
> - You can set the alignment of a table column by including a `:` in the corresponding cell of the separator line. A `:` on the left will make a column left-aligned (this is the default). A `:` on the right will make it right-aligned. Both, left and right `:`s will produce a center-aligned column.
>
>   ```
>   | left | center | right |
>   |:---- |:------:| -----:|
>   | One  | Two    | Three |
>   ```
>
>   | left | center | right |
>   | --- | --- | --- |
>   | One | Two | Three |
>
> #### Limitations
>
> Markdown tables come with a set of limitations. They don't support
> everything you can do with HTML tables, and that's on purpose. Each
> cell can only include **inline content** (text, images, links, inline
> code).
>
> You can't merge cells or rows.
>
> Block content like multiple paragraphs, lists, code blocks, sub-tables
> and other complex stuff does not work. If you're trying to mix a
> Markdown table with inline HTML, you might be up for a wild ride.
>
> You can't manually determine the width of a column. Your browser will
> decide what's a good width for any given column based on the content
> in your table.
>
> If you need more details, I recommend taking a peek at the
> [GitHub-flavored Markdown specification for
> tables](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-).